# How to express TCP-server socket as consumer endpoint with Camel and netty4?

Tags: java, apache-camel, netty

I want to create a TCP proxy using Apache Camel and the netty4 component.

How do I express, that the consumer endpoint (`.to(...)`) should be a TCP server socket - and not a client socket?

More specifically, I want this Camel route to connect to localhost:8001 and localhost:8002 as a client and to offer localhost:8003 as a TCP service that other applications can connect to to receive the data merged stream:

```
public class RouteBuilder extends org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder {
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("netty4:tcp://localhost:8001?textline=true&sync=false")
        .from("netty4:tcp://localhost:8002?textline=true&sync=false")
        .to("netty4:tcp://localhost:8003");
    }
}
```

In the example above the route tries to connect as a client to localhost:8003 - I want it to be a server socket.

Comment: See the options on the netty4 component in the docs, there is a clientMode.

Comment: Yup - but that solves only the consumer end. I also need the producer to behave non-standard; i.e. as a TCP server. Ideally I could write ´from("netty4:tcp://localhost:8001?clientMode=true). ... .to("netty4:tcp://:8003?serverMode=true")`.

Comment: Okay that is not supported